# What is a Band-Pass filter in Matlab? I need an explanation about matlab band-pass filters

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, noise-reduction

What is a Band Pass filter that we code in Matlab? I need a good explanation about it. Also i have searched on the google but those were discussed about circuits and transistors. So i just need a good explanation about BandPass Filtering in Matlab and LowPass Filtering in MatLab.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lowpass filter is a "method/device" by which from an input signal series, only the lower frequencies present (up to a given threshold frequency) in the input are passed through.

A highpass filter is the opposite of a lowpass filter in that the higher frequencies (greater than a given threshold frequency)  are passed through

A bandpass filter is a filter which passes through only a range ("band") of frequencies (between a low given threshold frequency and a high given threshold frequency)

MATLAB has functions to create any type of these filters (e.g http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html).

NOTE that there is not one unique method to create filters and various methods are used (e.g Butterworth, Chebyshev and so on), others are faster while others have nicer analytic properties and so on.

NOTE: If there is a more specific question abd filtering in MATLAB, can update answer to reflect that.

Comment: Hi Nikos, Is there anyway that we can consider bandpass/high-pass/low-pass filters as an AI technique.? if it isn't so what are the ways of arguments we can consider them as AI techniques?

Comment: @ArvindaSudan, there are many ways that signal filtering can be seen as an AI technique, either implicitly or explicitly. For example, implicitly any image/signal recognition process (AI) requires filtering. Explicitly is a rather different thing, in that a certain generalisation of filtering should be used, i'm not aware of any research in this direction although plausible

Comment: Thanks for your response @NikosM !. Is it possible for you to explain me about 'implicitly' signal recognition? will band-pass method can be considered under this or AI?

Comment: @ArvindaSudan, computer vision and speech recognition fall into the area of AI (artificial intelligence) and all these areas use signal processing techniques a lot, including filtering, so in this sense filtering is implicitly related to AI.